# Pass results (array) from controller into view and show it

Tags: php, controller

I'm experimenting with creating my own Joomla component. The component searches records in database tables, but I have a problem with how to show them.

I have a search form that sends the search phrase to the `controller.php`.

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <input name="company" id="form_hladat" maxlength="150" class="inputbox search-query input-medium" type="search" placeholder="hladat" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_regne" />
</form>
```

In the `controller.php` I have a search function. The function performs a search and redirects me to view `basic`.

```
public function search() {
    // Slashes cause errors, <> get stripped anyway later on. # causes problems.
    $badchars = array('#', '>', '<', '\\');
    $searchword = trim(str_replace($badchars, '', $this->input->getString('company', null, 'post')));

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();       
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('cin','tin','vatin','name','formatted_address','street','reg_number','building_number','postal_code','municipality','country','established_on','terminated_on','vatin_paragraph','registration_office','registration_number','formatted_street','street_number','rpo_organizations_id')))
        ->from($db->quoteName('corporate_bodies'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('cin') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote($searchword) . ' OR ' . $db->quoteName('name') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%'.$searchword.'%'));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $results = $rows;
    foreach ($results as $result):
        $name = $result->name;
        $cin = $result->cin;
        $rpo_id = $result->rpo_organizations_id;
        $company_demise = $result->terminated_on;
    endforeach;

    $view = $this->getView('basic','html');
    $view->results = $results;
    $view->display();
    //$this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_regne&view=basic', false));
}
```

And that's where my problem starts. I do not know how to get search results (array).

Answer (score 1):

Use your controller only for redirection purpose. For database stuff use your view model.
Make sure your view name, controller file name, model file name are same.

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline">
    <input name="company" id="form_hladat" maxlength="150" class="inputbox search-query input-medium" type="search" placeholder="hladat" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search.mySearch" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_regne" />
</form>
```

**components/com_regne/controllers/search.php**

```
function mySearch() {
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $term = $jinput->get('company', '', 'STRING');
    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_regne&view=search&q=' . $term, false));
}
```

**components/com_regne/models/search.php**

```
function getSearch() {

    $term = JRequest::getVar('q');
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();       
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('*')
        ->from($db->quoteName('corporate_bodies'));

    if (!empty($term)) {
        $query->where(
            [$db->quoteName('cin') . ' = ' . $db->quote($term),
            $db->quoteName('name') . ' LIKE ' . $db->q('%' . $db->escape($term, true) . '%', false)],
            'OR');
    }

    return $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList();
}
```

**components/com_regne/views/search/view.html.php** in display function

```
$this->results = $this->get('Search');
```

**components/com_regne/views/search/tmpl/default.php**

`$this->results` will contain your entire search results.

Comment: So what is the `null` function? Did you mean `is_null`? BTW, I prefer to use `if(isset($x) && !empty($x))` or something like that.

Comment: I have edited the controller and model function as well. Now have a check

Answer (score 0):

In the `display` function of the view, you should see the results in `$this->results`. It should work. If it doesn't display any data, then this means that most likely your `$results` array is empty. By the way, your `foreach` loop has no effect whatsoever on `$results`. In fact, if this is the whole code, then it has no effect whatsoever.